# Helidon 4 SE Unit Testing: How do I test my code with ServerRequest and ServerResponse

Tags: helidon, helidon-webclient, helidon-httpclient

I'm using Helidon 4 SE for a new service, and I would like to be able to test a function like this:

```
protected void myHandler(ServerRequest req, ServerResponse res)
```

I'm not as interested in the business logic at this point as the testing of this particular plumbing.

However, I'm having the hardest time finding and implementation of ServerRequest/Response.  [They are interfaces](https://helidon.io/docs/v4/apidocs/io.helidon.webserver/io/helidon/webserver/http/ServerRequest.html) and I just can't seem to find working implementations.  The answer may be between the difference SE and MP, but I can't find it.

I've tried a test with @ServerTest and ping the server with the provided client, but the debugger doesn't seem to attach to the thread the server runs in, so the client blows past my IntelliJ breakpoints.

Or, I'm missing something Helidon-ish (research indicates maybe JAX-RS-ish) that would allow me to create something that can be used as a io.helidon.webserver.http.ServerRequest.  I'm willing to use Mockito to mock it, but I feel like there's an implementation somewhere that I'm just not finding.

In my mind there should be something like

```
ServerRequest reqImpl = ServerRequest.Builder.withUrl("blah").withHeaders(<some headers>).build();
```

[Even in the examples](https://github.com/helidon-io/helidon/tree/main/examples) I'm not finding a good example of "test this service this way".

Any clues appreciated.

Comment: See https://helidon.io/docs/v4/#/se/testing Routing Tests section. In `@SetUpRoute` you should provide a mapping of your server endpoints. Best way to do it is to create implementation of `import io.helidon.webserver.http.HttpService` for example `FooService`.  These service would be used both in source code and in tests, but exception that all it's dependencies should be mocked for testing. `@SetUpRoute static void routing(HttpRouting.Builder builder) { var fooService= new FooService(); fooService.routing(builder); }` .

Answer (score 1):

Helidon's documentation features a section on testing, complete with [examples](https://helidon.io/docs/v4/#/se/testing#_examples). Does this get you going?